# Cannot mock BlobBaseClient.CanGenerateSasUri of Azure.Blob.Storage

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit, azure-blob-storage

I am currently writing test cases for my blob service.

I have passed almost all of the impediments of `Azure.Blob.Storage` except one.

I am trying to test a method which generates Url of the blobs which is dependent on `CanGenerateSasUri` property of the BlobClient. `if(blobClient.CanGenerateSasUri){}`.

The setup in the test is as below:

```
var url = new Uri("http://bogus:10000/devstoreaccount1/MyContainer/Blob.mp3");
var blobClient = new Mock<BlobClient>(MockBehavior.Default, url, (BlobClientOptions)null);
blobClient.SetupGet(x => x.CanGenerateSasUri).Returns(true);
```

But the Moq is complaining:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.CanGenerateSasUri
Non-overridable members (here: BlobBaseClient.get_CanGenerateSasUri) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

The error is valid as I can see that the property `BlobBaseClient.CanGenerateSasUri` is not virtual.

[image]

I found this([Cannot mock the BlobBaseClient.CanGenerateSasUri property for testing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/18224)) issue on GitHub.

It is mentioned in the issue that it is already solved and merged in the `master` branch.

But even in the latest version (12.8.4) the change is not present.

**Can someone help me bypass this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update to version 12.10.0. I have updated to the latest version 12.10.0 and it is working.